# Programming in C: How to avoid Type mismatches (expected 'signed char ', given 'signed char*')

Tags: c

So I have the following:

```
char myMessage[13] = "Hello world!";
printMessageToScreen(myMessage);

///////////////////////
//Method Declarations//
///////////////////////
printMessageToScreen(char message){
//do stuff
}
```

When I compile in CodeWarrior, I get Error C:1822: Type mismatch (expected 'signed char ', given 'signed char *')`

How has this type mismatch occurred? how can I avoid it? I have tried changing line 2 to `printMessageToScreen(myMessage[]);` but it gives me `Error C2450: Expected . * + 0 & ! ~ ++ -- -> [ (`

Comment: Replace `printMessageToScreen(char message){` with `printMessageToScreen(char* message){`.

Comment: Avoid it the same way you avoid poking your eye with a fork: don't do it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
printMessageToScreen(char message){
```

means that you have a one-byte character value in `message`. On the other hand,

```
printMessageToScreen(char *message){
```

means that `message` is a pointer/array reference and will solve this particular problem of yours.

C distinguishes between values, like a `char message`, and pointers to memory that store data structures such as arrays, like `char *message`, which is a pointer to the memory that stores the array containing the consecutive character values in the string `"Hello world!"`.

Answer (score 1):

Change the function signature to

```
void printMessageToScreen(char* message){
// do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because your 'myMessage' is a string and your function printMessageToScreen is expecting a single character argument. You can fix it by changing the function so it expects a pointer.

```
printMessageToScreen(char * message){
//do stuff
}
```

When you call it with printMessageToScreen(myMessage) you're passing the address of the string 'myMessage'